# PHP spl_autoload_register is doing nothing

Tags: php, oop, autoload

i'm updating my code and trying to use spl_autoload_register but IT SIMPLY DOESN'T WORK!!!
I'm using PHP 5.3.8 - Apache 2.22 on Centos / Ubuntu / Win7 and trying to echo something but i get nothing instead... have been trying to make it work for the last 3 hours with no result... this is driving me mad!!!

```
class ApplicationInit {
    // Constructor
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'classesAutoloader'));
        echo 'construct working...!';
    }

    // Autoloading methods
    public function classesAutoloader($class) {
        include 'library/' . $class . '.php';

        echo 'autoload working...!';
    }
}
```

first echo from __construct works but the "classesAutoloader" doesn't work at all, this class is defined in a php file within a folder and i'm calling it from index.php like follows:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', getcwd() . DS);
define('APP', ROOT . 'application' . DS);

// Initializing application
require(APP.'appInit.php');
$classAuto = new ApplicationInit();
```

any help is truly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see `'construct working...!'`?

Comment: It's not doing anything because you're not trying to reference any non-loaded classes. After `$classAuto`, add something like `new SomeClassThatDoesntExist()`, and you'll see `classsesAutoloader()` attempting to load some class that doesn't exit.

Comment: yes I do, thanks for your answer, however... doing what you just said seems to me that is the same as doing the file include without spl_autoload_register...

Comment: @CABP who are you talking to?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're doing the wrong thing. The function that you pass to `spl_autoload_register` is what's responsible for loading the class file.

Your code is calling

```
$classAuto = new ApplicationInit();
```

but by that time, `ApplicationInit` is already loaded so the autoload function doesn't get called

A more logical way  would be for you to to call

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    include 'library/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Then when you call

```
$something = new MyClass();
```

And the `MyClass` is not defined, then it will call your function to load that file and define the class.

Comment: I don't think his problem is that the `ApplicationInit` class isn't loaded, but that the others classes are not... I think that *your* answer is 100% wrong and out of the subject, not mine.

Comment: so, I should use spl_autoload_register directly from index.php right? if i do that how do i pass the 'ApplicationInit' function to the $class parameter???

Comment: @CABP The code you have, as weird as it is ( I would use what I suggested in the answer), should be working. The reason nothing is happening is because you are not attempting to auto load any classes. for it to work, you need to call new MyCustomClass(), then it will look for MyCustomClass.php in your library folder

Comment: this is what I got when using $something = new MyClass() Warning: include(application/MyClass.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory same thing when trying to use 'library' directory

Comment: @CABP Do you really not see what that message means? That class doesn't exist, use a class name that is in your library folder. The path also needs to be relative to where index.php is

Comment: @JuanMendes yes I do see what that message means, it's still happening with existent and non existent classes...

Comment: @CABP To solve the problem at hand, why don't you look with an absolute path? It's not what you should use in the end, but it'll lead to to where the problem is. Some versions of php have a hard time figuring out what the current directory is. You can also try adding `chdir(dirname(__FILE__))` to the top of your index.php to avoid those problems.

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem? Your code is working correctly.

```
class ApplicationInit {
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'classesAutoloader'));
        echo 'construct working...!';
    }

    public function classesAutoloader($class) {
        include 'library/' . $class . '.php';

        echo 'autoload working...!';
    }
}

$classAuto = new ApplicationInit(); //class already loaded so dont run autoload

$newclass = new testClass(); //class not loaded so run autoload
```